# Layers in PixiJS

Tags: javascript, sprites, blending, alpha-blending

I am using the PixiJS framework to create a 2D RPG Game.

How can I create a `PIXI.Container` with a transparent background which I can render on top of my main stage container?

My goal is it to have 4 layers which contain `PIXI.Sprite`s and `PIXI.Text`s:

layer 1 should be rendered beneath the player
layer 2 should be rendered above layer 1
layer 3 should be rendered above the player and above layer 1 and layer 2
layer 4 should be rendered above everything else for debug information

In case I can cannot use multiple `PIXI.Container` then how else could I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason don't want to use preordered containers, then you need to sort the render list.